# Личный кабинет пользователя

Tags: php

У каждого пользователя есть личный кабинет. Как сделать, чтобы можно было видеть информации у других пользователей в личном кабинете у пользователя (как вконтакте, когда нажимаешь на своего друга, переносит на его кабинет). Но могу понять, как реализовать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @angers777, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните...

Comment: Вам код привести? =))) Думайте своей головой, она вам нужна не для того, чтобы пирожки кушать. Решив проблему самостоятельно, вы избавите себя от похожих проблем и, возможно, их производных в будущем.

Comment: "У меня есть сайт, хочу юзерленту в него, кто сделает бесплатно?" - как то так выглядит вопрос

Comment: VasyOk
"Не могу понять, как реализовать?" и "Сделайте бесплатно", есть разница??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['user_id'])){ // если передан id пользователя
    echo "информация о стороннем пользователе";
}
else{
    // тут ещё должна быть проверка на авторизованность
    // если пользователь вошел в личный кабинет, выводим информацию о нем
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вконтакте это реализовано так. При переходе на страницу другого пользователя, получается `user_id` того пользователя, к которому вы вошли и следовательно все данные по этому `user_id` с помощью `select и mysql_fetch_assoc` берутся из бд.